# C++ create an std::packaged_task of a generic std::bind

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, generic-programming

I simply try to create a `std::packaged_task` for a given `std::bind`.

```
#include <functional>
#include <future>

class A
{
public:
  template<class T>
  void execute(T func)
  {
    std::packaged_task<T> task(func);
  }
};

int main()
{
  auto func = std::bind([](int x) { return x*x; }, 5);

  A name;

  name.execute(func);
}
```

> main.cpp: In instantiation of 'void A::execute(T) [with T =
>   std::_Bind(int)>]': main.cpp:20:20:   required
>   from here main.cpp:10:36: error:
>   'std::packaged_task(int)> > task' has
>   incomplete type
>        std::packaged_task task(func);

I'm using G++ 5.2.0, and C++14.

Does someone have an idea?

Thank you,

Comment: How is `func` supposed to be called? And what is it supposed to return, if any?

Comment: `auto` is not allowed in a parameter declaration.

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't compile

Comment: T.C, it should return anything, depending of the std::bind

Comment: I see a bunch of problems in your code almost completely unrelated to your problem.  Your use of `auto` is not compliant to C++11.  Your use of `decltype` indicates to me that you do not know what it does.  I'm not sure how "in theory this should work" means to you.  You have also not understood T.C.s question: the `func` passed in, how would you expect it to be called?  Do you expect to pass it an integer?  Nothing?  A string?  Three chickens and a goat?  The result of `std::bind` doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Provide your best attempt.  Have it actually compile, as best you can.  Fix any errors you understand.  Once you have fixed all the errors you understand, remove anything that is not relevant to the errors you do not understand how to fix.  Ask about *that* error and how to fix it.  Include context (what you are trying to do).  -- Or, alternatively, ask how to do something.  Don't get hung up on syntax.  Say what you are trying to do, give an example of how you want to use it, and list what is *required*.

Comment: Alright, I'll try to give you a better insight

Comment: For information, I'm using C++14 and auto is allowed as a parameter

Comment: auto as a parameter is not in C++14 either (outside of lambdas).  It is proposed in something that will probably make it into C++1z.  Note that if you want to reply to someone, type @their_user_name, otherwise your comments will not notify them.  (You get notified because this is your question, even if I don't "@" ping you).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of c++11 it is not possible to declare function arguments as auto (I believe its part of c++17). Unfortunately I don't have a compiler which supports that feature and I'm not quite sure of its semantics but a workaround would be to use templates:

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <functional>

template<class T>
void execute(std::function<T> func) // is a std::bind
{
    std::packaged_task<T> task(func);
    //...
}
```

which you can use like this:

```cpp
std::function<int()> func = std::bind([](int x) { return x*x; }, 5);
execute(func);
```

The problem why you get this error is that `std::packaged_task` is only specialized for template arguments of the form `ReturnType(Args...)`. So if you pass something different like the `std::_Binder` returned from `std::bind` or a `std::function` it appears as undefined.

**Edit**

Concerning your comment about deducing the type of the std::function:

Instead of using `std::bind()` you could use lambdas.

If you have a class `A` with the function `doSomething(int x)` like in your comment:

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    int doSomething(int x)
    {
        return x *x;
    }
};
```

We need to change the execute function to the following (see Yakk's answer):

```cpp
template<class F, class...Args>
void execute(F&& func, Args&&...args)
{
    using zF = std::decay_t<F>&&;
    using R = std::result_of_t< zF(Args...) >;
    std::packaged_task<R()> task(
        std::bind([func = std::forward<F>(func)](auto&&...args)mutable->R{
        return std::move(func)(decltype(args)(args)...);
    }, std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        );
}
```

Now you can use it like that:

```
A a;

auto f = [](A& inst, int x) {  return inst.doSomething(x); };
execute(f, a, 5);

// or

auto g = [&]() { return a.doSomething(5); };
execute(g);
```

**Note**

Be aware of the life time of `a` as the packaged_task may run asynchronously.

Comment: I'm afraid but this doesn't compile,

main.cpp:10:36: error: 'std::packaged_task<std::_Bind<main()::<lambda(int)>(int)> > task' has incomplete typestd::packaged_task<T> task(func);

Comment: But that's exactly the idea and where the problem is coming from.

Comment: Oh I'm sry of course you have to include the <future> header. Edited my Post

Comment: I've modified my original post, that's not the <future> header causing the troubles

Comment: Yep you are right. I got it now. It seems that `std::packaged_task` expects a template parameter of the form  `ReturnType(Args...)`. See my modified answer.

Comment: It's working for me either, but there is another problem now, how to deduct the type of this std::function?

Comment: I'm afraid thats not possible as the standard does not define the return type of `std::bind`. Instead it just specifies requirements for the returned type which include, amongst others, that it must be convertible to `std::function`

Comment: Hum and let's say we have the type of the method like A::doSomething, how could we manage to assign it to a std::function by making it deduce?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
template<class...Args, class F>
void execute(F&& func)
{
  using R = std::result_of_t< std::decay_t<F>(Args...) >;
  std::packaged_task<R(Args...)> task(std::forward<F>(func));
}
```

I added perfect forwarding, and the option to pass in arguments.  If you don't pass in arguments, it assumes the passed in callable takes 0 arguments.

Example use:

```
auto func = std::bind([](int x) { return x*x; }, 5);
A name;
name.execute(func);
```

if `func` requires arguments, you have to pass them explicitly.  Which is only fair, as it is hard to use a `std::packaged_task` without knowing what arguments it will expect.  ;)

This also compiles:

```
auto func = [](int x) { return x*x; };
A name;
name.execute<int>(func);
```

but how you are going to use that packaged task is tricky.

If you want to mimic the interfaces of `std::async` and the like, we can do:

```
template<class F, class...Args>
void execute(F&& func, Args&&...args)
{
  using zF = std::decay_t<F>&&;
  using R = std::result_of_t< zF(Args...) >;
  std::packaged_task<R()> task(
    std::bind( [func=std::forward<F>(func)](auto&&...args)mutable->R{
      return std::move(func)(decltype(args)(args)...);
    }, std::forward<Args>(args)... )
  );
}
```

which carefully wraps the passed in `func` in a lambda in order to avoid calling `bind` on `bind`, and then binds the arguments passed in.

Now you can:

```
name.execute([](int x){ return x*x; }, 5);
```

without using `bind` at all.

The code above has not been compiled, and probably contains tpyos.

Comment: std::move(func)(decltype(args)(args)...); i can not understand what and how this statement is formed and used????can you just explain why twi (args) and where would have been 2 bind used???

Comment: @ahmedallam `decltype(x)` is the type of `x` is declared as.  `decltype(x)(x)` is `x` cast to the type it was declared as.  `std::move(func)` casts `func` to an rvalue reference.  `std::move(func)( decltype(x)(x) )` calls `func` as an rvalue on `x`, where `x` is cast to the type it is declared as.  `decltype(args)(args)...` expands a parameter pack `args`.  `std::move(func)( decltype(args)(args)... )` expands `args` as the types it is declared as and calls `func` with that, where `func` is cast to an rvalue reference.

Comment: thanks a lot.i understand the syntax now but i wonder how did you think of the solution???the problem solving technique to reach this complex syntax is what i hope to understand.i will reread the answer.thanks again+1

Comment: how to return task from inside the function to be used to get future and post to io_service??